# Sudo commands just go to newline

Tags: bash, sudo

When entering sudo commands, my system sometimes arbitrarily doesnt execute the command but goes to a newline.

For instance, typing sudo apt-get update and hitting enter just goes to a blank newline where I can carry on typing.

When I reset my machine, two out of five times it goes back to normal which is quite baffling given that I don't really change anything between resets.

Can anyone provide any insights as to why my system does this?

I am using the Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Please note I have also asked this on Super User and re asked it here because I figured it is more appropriate to ask it here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this cross-posted. Cross-posting is discouraged across the SE network.

Comment: There's nothing like "reset" in Ubuntu AFAIK.

Comment: What command(s) would you recommend to do such a reset or restoration?

Comment: What other commands "just go to newline"?